# Enforcing Minimum Order Weight

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, cart-rule

I have a store which sells fresh and frozen food. We need customers to order a minimum of 8kgs of frozen produce to ensure product arrives in a frozen state.

We currently have product attributes called "Fresh" & "Frozen"

What's the best way to have a minimum order (by weight)? Eg dont allow the order if the amount of frozen food is under 8kg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would enforce this constraint in the cart using an observer. That way, you can notify the customer before they start checkout (and not make them annoyed).

`checkout_cart_save_before` seems like a decent candidate to hook onto with an observer. Have the observer check the weight of the cart items and thrown an exception with a warning message using the checkout session to notify the customer about the weight restriction.

Some pseudocode..

```
// In Observer
$quote = $observer->getCart();
foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {  // Iterate through items listed in the cart only
    // Add up the weights
}
// Throw exception if added weight doesn't meet the restriction
```

Note that if you have parent-child products, make sure you retrieve the correct weight from the simple products you have. I think when you use configurable products, the simple product's attributes may not be used (e.g. price is pulled from the configurable product, if you buy a simple product associated with a configurable product).